# how to check validation error on submit button click in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model-validation

I have one View and in which there 3 partial views are rendering.

And there is one Save button on the parent view(Index,in which the partial views are rendering).This Save button is common for all of the partial views.

> > My problem is, i am not getting the way in which i can check is there any model validation is firing on any of the partial views while click on Save button.

I used below check on Save button click :-

```
var status = $('form').valid();
```

But its not checking the validations of all the partial views.Its just checking the validations in that particular partial view in which i am clicking the Save button.

Comment: Are you using ValidationFor helpers? Unobstrusive validation is enable for the application? Are you including JqueryValidation file? Post the cshtml to help us to help you!

Comment: Yes..i am using ValidationFor helpers.

Comment: You should post the View code!

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for that.We can simply check the length of "input-validation-error" class on form's submit event.Just like that :-

if($(".input-validation-error").length == 0)
{
    //there is no validation on form.
}else
{
    //validation is firing somewhere.
}